# QueryParseException in query generated by string concatenation?

Tags: java, sparql, jena

I'm generating and trying to execute a query using the following code, after loading an ontology from a file into a model.

```
   package rdf;
   import java.util.Scanner;

   import org.apache.jena.atlas.io.IndentedWriter;
   import org.apache.jena.atlas.logging.LogCtl;
   import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
   import org.apache.jena.query.Query;
   import org.apache.jena.query.QueryExecution;     
   import org.apache.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
   import org.apache.jena.query.QueryFactory;
   import org.apache.jena.query.QuerySolution;
   import org.apache.jena.query.ResultSet;
   import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Model;
   import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
   import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode;
   import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Resource;
   import org.apache.jena.util.FileManager;
   import org.apache.jena.vocabulary.RDF;
   public class disease {
   public static final String onto_file = "root-ontology.owl";
   public static final String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");

   private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("disease");
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    LogCtl.setCmdLogging();
       // create the simplest model there is
       final Model m = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
       // use the file manager to read an RDF document into the model
       FileManager.get().readModel(m, onto_file);
       String re;
       System.out.println("Enter class name : ");
          Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);
          re = scanIn.nextLine();
       String queryString =        
             "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> "+
                       "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>  "+
                 " PREFIX  : <http://www.semanticweb.org/ hp/ontologies/2016/2/disease-ontologies.owl#>"+
               "select ?x " 
                + 
               "where { "+
                "  :"+re +" a ?x}";
              ;
           Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
           QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query,m);
          ResultSet results =  qe.execSelect();
          String  s= results.toString();
                                while(results.hasNext()) {
                                  int i  =0;
            QuerySolution  binding =results.nextSolution();
            Resource su=(Resource) binding.get("x");
            System.out.println(su.getLocalName());

            String[]r = null;
         String re1=su.getLocalName();
        System.out.println(re);
        r[i]=re1;}}
   }
```

I get the following QueryParseException.  Why?

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.query.QueryParseException: Encountered " "<" "< "" at line 1, column 124.
Was expecting:
  <IRIref> ...
```

Comment: The code is mangled.

Comment: @AndyS I've changed the code to the one below the "EDIT", and now I'm getting a new error shown above.

Comment: What's the value of `re`?  Try printing your query before trying to execute it.  Also, if you add newlines to your query string, you'll get much more helpful error messages (because you'll have a column number **and** a line number).

Comment: @ JoshuaTaylor "re" is the name of the class that I'm trying to print its individuals. When I tried to print it I get this:


         PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>   PREFIX  : <http://www.semanticweb.org/ hp/ontologies/2016/2/disease-      ontologies.owl#>select ?x where {   :class name a ?x}


I tried implementing the query in different ways but still, I couldn't reach the required results.

Comment: There is a space between `:class` and `name` in your last shown output, i.e. you have `:class name a ?x.` That's not a triple pattern anymore.

Comment: @Ciba AKSW is right, when you paste in the string "class name", you end up `:class name a ?x`, which isn't legal.  If you want to inject into a query like this, you should make the query string something like `?className a ?x`, and use a ParameterizedSparqlString (there are examples on Stack Overflow) to inject your value into the query.  String concatenation opens you up to all sorts of attacks.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor @ AKSW: I changed query's code & the error no longer appeared but I'm not getting any results. I added to the code:    
 ResultSet results =  qe.execSelect(); String  s= results.toString(); System.out.println(s);
     And got this output:    

PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>   PREFIX  : <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing>select ?x where {   :bones_diseases a ?x}
org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.ResultSetCheckCondition@1187c9e8
    Am I writing the query wrong? Ps: any good resources?

Comment: `?x a ?y` says that `?x` is an instance of `?y`.  Wouldn't you want to ask for `?x a :bones_diseases`, so as to find instances of the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code to the following, and it worked perfectly, the concept is still the same though. The code now returns the individuals of a class, store it in an array and print it:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package rdf;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModel;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModelSpec;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QuerySolution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;
import org.apache.jena.atlas.logging.LogCtl;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.apache.jena.atlas.io.IndentedWriter;
import org.apache.jena.atlas.logging.LogCtl;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

/**
*
* @author shroog
*/
public class JavaApplication14 {


// public static final String onto_file = "root-ontology.owl";
//    public static final String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
//    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("disease");
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    //LogCtl.setCmdLogging();
       // create the simplest model there is
      // final Model m = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
       // use the file manager to read an RDF document into the model
       //FileManager.get().readModel(m, onto_file);

      OntModel m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM );
            FileManager.get().readModel( m, "root-ontology.owl" );

             String var="";
       System.out.println("Enter class name : ");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
          var = sc.nextLine();
            String queryString =        
                     "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> "+
                               "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>  "+
                         " PREFIX  : <http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2016/2/disease-ontologies.owl#>"+
                       "select ?x " 
                        + 
                       "where { "+
                        "?x a :"+var+"}";



               Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
               QueryExecution qee = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query,m);
                  ResultSet resultss =  qee.execSelect();
                                       String [] TXT= new String[20];
                  try{

            int i=0;
              while(resultss.hasNext()) {


                QuerySolution  bindingg =resultss.nextSolution();
                Resource suu=(Resource) bindingg.get("x");

                TXT[i]= suu.getLocalName();
                                    System.out.println(TXT[i]);
                                    i++;

                               }
                  } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){}

                                       }


}
```